# Transforming existing cache as map to Spring @Cacheable

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching, jooq

Currently, I have a method that makes an insertion on the database using Jooq store method. Each time a record is stored, it is added to a local cache, which is basically a map with an Id that comes from front (which I need to store for later uses) and the Id that is generated on save. So basically:

```
private Map<String, Integer> cache = new HashMap<>();
public insert(List<Customer> customers>{

     //some code to convert Customer to jooq generated CustomerRecord, 
     //which implements UpdatableRecord from Jooq

     record.store();
     cache.put(record.getFrontId(), record.getId());
}
public int find(String frontId) { return cache.get(frontId); }
```

It's all currently working, but the managing of all this is requiring a lot of effort. How to use a caching like this with Spring @Cacheable? I've never used it, but I tried adding 
`@CacheEvict(value="customer", key="#frontId")` to the find method, but of course the cache is empty when it is invoked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example for you... (Parameter is automatically the cache key (you can specify it with (key="#search.keyword) in Cacheable):

```
@Cacheable(value="customercache")
public Customer find(String customerkey) {
    return //Load some customer; 
 }
```

1. The cache looks if he can find the customerkey in his implemented cache, if it has the key, it returns the customer and the method body isnt invoke.

   2. If the cache dont find any key entry, it invokes the body and return the customer, now it is stored in the cache, too.

Really import is, dont forget to activate caching in the main method.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableCaching
public class Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}

}
```

Comment: Saving the whole customer entity isn't overkill? I need only it's Id

Comment: than you return only the id there